# How to know about the apps installed on the android device

Tags: android

I am working on a web based mobile application where user can select different applications and when clicked on install, it will open the Google-play-store link for that application. The user can now install the applications from the play-store. But, the playsore will be opened as a separate window.

That's how, several playstore windows will be opened if the user selects multiple applications to install.

I want the playstore windows to be opened one after another once an installation is completed, but, from the mobile browser (as this is not an apk and uses HTML/Java scripts), it is hard to know whether one app is installed on the device (due to security reasons). I have read about the [Google purchase status APIs](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/gp-purchase-status-api.html). But this requires several fields like package-id, product-id, purchase tokens to get the purchase status of the app.

Can anyone help me with the scenario that I have mentioned above? Can I use the Google purchase or Google Wallet APIs for my problem ? It would be fine if anyone can suggest any other solution for this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

No, from HTML it is not possible to know what apks have been installed on the device running the web app.

The Google purchase APIs are for in-app purchases - they also do not tell you what apps a users has purchased (and apps purchased is not equal to apps installed anyway).

As the answer from Booger mentions, if you throw out doing this from HTML, and write an installable app, then you can find out about other installed apps (and this requires no specific permissions to do so).

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Would you suggest any other ways to achieve my requirement. Right now, I have put a timer which pops the next Google play store window after every 30 seconds. This way if the page says 3 apps and the user selects all 3, first one pops immediately, second one after 30 seconds and the 3rd after 60 seconds. I would appreciate if you can suggest any better idea.

Comment: As a user I'd find this timed popup behaviour very annoying.  Your requirements are simply impossible - if you stick with HTML, then you cannot control the install process.  Even if you send someone to the Google Play store webpage, there is no guarantee that they end up installing the app anyway - their device may not be compatible, they may be geographically blocked from the app, they may cancel etc

Comment: Thanks. It seems you are right. But, I was wondering how is it possible with Google play store. I could see about the app installed in the play-store web page. Would you please let me know whether my understanding about the play-store is correct or not?

Answer (score 0):

For knowing which apps are installed on a device currently, you can use the `PackageManager` to query your device and get this information.

There is a Broadcast you can register for, to be notified by the system when an app has been installed on a device.

To register for this broadcast, have something like this in your manifest:

```
<receiver
        android:name="com.yourpackage.service.InstallReceiver"
        android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED" />

            <data android:scheme="package" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Then you will create a class named InstallReceiver, and have something like this in there:

```
public class InstallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
        final String packageLink = intent.getData().toString();

            EasyTracker.getInstance().setContext(context);
            final Tracker trackerV2 = EasyTracker.getTracker();
            trackerV2.trackEvent("app_action", "installed", packageLink, null);

    }
        ....
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply . But the solution you are providing needs an app to be installed on the device. But, my requirement is that, I want to know about the apps installed in the device from the web page (HTML/java scripts). The web page actually redirects to the Google play store to install apps. Right now, the apps can be installed in parallel, but I want it to be sequential one after another, and for that I should know whether the previous app is installed before redirecting to the playstore for the next app.

Comment: Concur with answer that you cannot do what you want without an app installed (ie. can't do what you are asking).